# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT' - Unable to modify table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, partitioning

I have created a table from this script. The databases are partitioned.

```
print 'Create Table - tenant_Import'
go

create table tenant_Import
(
    Import_Data_Id bigint not null identity(100000000000000, 1),
    Audit_Login_Id bigint not null default 0,
    Tenant_Id bigint not null,
    Tenant_Partition bigint not null,
    Map_Id bigint not null,
    Filename nvarchar(500)  not null,
    DataFile varbinary(max) not null,
    Status int not null,
    DateInserted datetime not null DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    DateProcessed datetime null
)
on partition_name_Data(Tenant_Partition)
go

grant select, insert, update, delete on tenant_Import to a_named_role
go

alter table tenant_Import
add constraint pk_Import_Data 
  primary key (Tenant_Partition, Tenant_Id, Import_Data_Id)
  on partition_name_Data(Tenant_Partition)
go

create index ix1_Import_Data 
on tenant_Import (Tenant_Partition, Tenant_Id, Map_Id)
with fillfactor = 75
on partition_name_Index(Tenant_Partition)
go
```

I added rows ok into this table.

If I try and change a value (such as null to not null) and click save in SSMS then I get an error:

> 'tenant_Import' table
>   - Unable to modify table.   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.

Any idea on what could be causing this? This is in SQL Server 2005 Enterprise.

==============================================================================
The change script as requested by some comments/answers is as follows (I changed DateInserted from not null to null, but the error message happens if I try and change any column):

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tenant_Import
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF__tenant_Im__Audit__740F363E
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tenant_Import
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF__tenant_Im__DateI__75035A77
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import
    (
    Import_Data_Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (101000000000000, 1),
    Audit_Login_Id bigint NOT NULL,
    Tenant_Id bigint NOT NULL,
    Tenant_Partition bigint NOT NULL,
    Map_Id bigint NOT NULL,
    Filename nvarchar(500) NOT NULL,
    DataFile varbinary(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Status int NOT NULL,
    DateInserted datetime NULL,
    DateProcessed datetime NULL
    )  ON partition_name_Data(Tenant_Partition) 
     TEXTIMAGE_ON  DEFAULT 
GO
GRANT DELETE ON dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import TO a_named_role  AS dbo
GO
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import TO a_named_role  AS dbo
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import TO a_named_role  AS dbo
GO
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import TO a_named_role  AS dbo
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF__tenant_Im__Audit__740F363E DEFAULT ((0)) FOR Audit_Login_Id
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF__tenant_Im__DateI__75035A77 DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR DateInserted
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.tenant_Import)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import (Import_Data_Id, Audit_Login_Id, Tenant_Id, Tenant_Partition, Map_Id, Filename, DataFile, Status, DateInserted, DateProcessed)
        SELECT Import_Data_Id, Audit_Login_Id, Tenant_Id, Tenant_Partition, Map_Id, Filename, DataFile, Status, DateInserted, DateProcessed FROM dbo.tenant_Import WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import OFF
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.tenant_Import
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_tenant_Import', N'tenant_Import', 'OBJECT' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tenant_Import ADD CONSTRAINT
    pk_Import_Data PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Tenant_Partition,
    Tenant_Id,
    Import_Data_Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON partition_name_Data(Tenant_Partition) 

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix1_Import_Data ON dbo.tenant_Import
    (
    Tenant_Partition,
    Tenant_Id,
    Map_Id
    ) WITH( PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 75, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON partition_name_Index(Tenant_Partition) 
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you push the "Generate Change Script" button and post that?  It might reveal the Syntax error.

Comment: This has to do with partitioning from what I'm reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use SSMS to change tables - SSMS is not working anything other then just generating a change script and executing it for you.

You can right click in you design window and choose `Generate Change Script...` to check the script yourself before running it.

SSMS is not all-powerful and those scripts can have mistakes. There are often times when you can't use it to change table but have to write an command yourself. In fact I would strongly recommend to use it for table changes as little as possible as it often over-complicate simple operations.

You can change NOT NULL to NULL column (Map_Id as example):

```
ALTER TABLE tenant_Import_Data
ALTER COLUMN Map_Id BIGINT NULL
```

Comment: Rolled back 3rd party edit which inappropriately changed table name.